# Android Multi-touch: Pointers with index > 0 not triggering event.Action_Move

Tags: android, multi-touch

In my multitouch program I'm encountering a runtime error where the Multitouch logic for a pointer sliding on the screen (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) is only entered by the initial pointer. This means the code within my switch statement for case ACTION_MOVE is only accessible by the first finger to touch the screen, aka pointer index = 0. The following is the relevant parts of my code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // get pointer index from the event object
        int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();
        // get pointer ID
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        // get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
        int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (maskedAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            // We have a new pointer. Lets add it to the list of pointers
            PointF f = new PointF();
            f.x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            f.y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
            mActivePointers.put(pointerId, f);
            Log.d("Multitouch", "x coord = " + Float.toString(f.x));
            Log.d("Multitouch", "y coord = " + Float.toString(f.y));
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { // a pointer was moved
            Log.e("Multitouch", "Pointer"+ Integer.toString(pointerId) +" is moving");
            for (int size = event.getPointerCount(), i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                PointF f = mActivePointers.get(event.getPointerId(i));
                if (f != null) {
                    f.x = event.getX(i);
                    f.y = event.getY(i);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointers.remove(pointerId);
            break;
        }
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

Needless to say I want the code in Action_Move to be triggered by any pointer, not just the initial pointer. What is preventing pointers beyond index zero from triggering a move event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the Documentation, `MotionEvent.getActionIndex()` only returns the Index for `ACTION_POINTER_UP` and `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionIndex%28%29). You however use the pointer ID generated from the pointer Index returned by said function in your log output. Hence, the log is incorrect, as the function doesn't return what you expect.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you're trying to say. Even if getActionIndex() only works within ACTION_POINTER_UP and ACTION_POINTER_DOWN shouldn't other pointers still be able to enter the ACTION_MOVE code?

Comment: Yeah, the ´ACTION_MOVE´ should work for all the pointers, and I am saying it is working, your debug log just outputs that it is not. In my project it is working using a loop looping through all the pointers just like you do.

Comment: It most certainly is not working. I have different sounds playing based on which coordinate a pointer is in and right now only the first pointer (index 0) dynamically changes the sound playing when moved to a new coordinate. The rest continue playing the sound for the coordinate they touched when the Action_POINTER_Down was fired.

Comment: I really don't know what's wrong, because it's working fine for me. I'm afraid you'll have to ask a new question and post your code again.